# Obtaining my device token using PushApps

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, pushapps

How can I obtain APNS my device token using [PushApps](http://www.pushapps.mobi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very simple:

1. Implement the **PushAppsDelegate** method - http://wiki.pushapps.mobi/display/PUSHAPPS/PushApps+Delegation#PushAppsDelegation-PushToken.
2. The object **pushToken** is what’s you need!